# How to add the numbers displayed

Tags: java

Now how do i add the numbers displayed and print them ?
i got how to display them but cant figure out how to add the number please would be a great help for my project

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number: \n");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while(i <= n){
            System.out.print(i);
            if(i == n){
            System.out.print("=");
            }
            else{
            System.out.print("+");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for addition you need 2 operands... one is coming from the terminal input... but the other???

Comment: Do you know how to do simple arithmetic operations in any language?

Comment: System.out.println(sc.nextInt() + sc.nextInt()) - enter and add two number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another variable `int sum` to update the sum of all `i`'s with each loop iteration:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number: \n");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;    // Create a sum variable
        while(i <= n){
            System.out.print(i);
            sum+=i;     // Add `i` to sum
            if(i == n){
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.println(sum); // Display `sum` after loops finish
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("+");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another variable for the running total. To be more concise, use a `for` loop, and handle the `i == n` outside of the loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Number: \n");
int n = sc.nextInt();
int i = 0, sum = n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += i;
    System.out.print(i + "+");
}
System.out.println(n + "=" + sum);
```